# Retrieving Card details from Square Customer

Tags: square-connect

I'm trying to create a recurring payment on Square, ala Stripe subscriptions. However, I am having trouble retrieving a customer's card information (specifically `customer_card_id`) to pass into [Charge](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#endpoint-charge).

Our flow is such:

1. A customer visits to our store and subscribes to a membership, which we process via the point of sale app.
2. We continuously poll Square to retrieve payment information, and create membership records appropriately.
3. When the user's membership period expires, charge them for the next month's membership.

When researching [RetrieveCustomer](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#endpoint-retrievecustomer), I find that there is a `cards` property under `Customer`, but iterating through all the `Customers` under our account, they all have `cards = None` despite us having taken card payments via the point of sale app.

Also, looking at [ListTransactions](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#endpoint-listtransactions), there doesn't seem to be anything that might be `customer_card_id`. The IDs I see there are tender ID, location ID, and transaction ID. The `card_fingerprint` also looks promising but that doesn't seem right either, since a [card can have both an ID and a fingerprint](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#type-card).

Am I missing something? Where might I find `customer_card_id`?

---

EDIT

Looks like I was dumb and my local instance of our application was just out of date with transactions from Square. After updating my data with customers we've processed since the last time I updated, customers with a non-`None` `card` property now show up. [tristansokol's answer below is still valid however.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45177805/1946801)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you process the first charge? You need to explicitly add the card on file, it won't be added by default from processing a transaction from a customer. See: https://squareup.com/help/us/en/article/5770-use-card-on-file-with-the-square-point-of-sale-app